# I get an error signInResult:failed code=10

Tags: google-signin

`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val btn: View = findViewById<View>(R.id.sign_in_button)

    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
    val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        signIn(mGoogleSignInClient)
    }
}

private fun signIn(mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient) {
    val signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 123)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 123) {

        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        Log.d("MyLog", task.toString())

        handleSignInResult(task)
    }
}

private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {

            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        Log.d("MyLog", account.idToken.toString())

    } catch (e: ApiException) {

        Log.d("MyLog", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)

    }
}
```

}
`

I signed up with google cloud:[eGoogle cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJzLN.png)

When you select an account in the window from Google, the log comes out signInResult:failed code=10